# Prove that $\mu \otimes \lambda(C)=\int f d\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let, $(\Omega, A, \mu)$ be a sigma-finite measure space and $f : \Omega \to \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ . Consider, $(\Omega \times [0,+\infty),A \otimes \beta([0,+\infty)), \mu \otimes \lambda)$ and the set $C:=\{(\omega,t) \in \Omega \times [0,+\infty): f(\omega) \ge t\}$.
>
> Then prove that,(i) $C \in A \otimes \beta([0,+\infty))$ and (ii) $\mu \otimes \lambda(C)=\int f d\mu$

My attempt:

Could do nothing with (i).

Tried (ii) : $$\mu \otimes \lambda(C)=\int_{\Omega} \lambda(C_{\omega}) d\mu=\int_{\Omega} \lambda\{t \in [o,+\infty):f(\omega)\ge t\} d\mu=\int_{\Omega}\int_{0}^{f(\omega)} d\lambda \text{ }d\mu$$ $$=\int_{\Omega} \int_{0}^\infty1_{f(\omega)\ge t} d\lambda \text{ } d\mu=  \int_{0}^\infty (\int_{\Omega}1_{f(\omega) \ge t} \text{ } d\mu) d\lambda $$ $$=\int_{0}^\infty\mu(f(\omega) \ge t)d\lambda$$

I have reached here!

Thanks in Advance for help!

Comment: The formula $\int f\,d\mu=\int_0^\infty \mu\{\omega: f(\omega)>t\}\,dt$ is true for general $\mu$, no $\sigma$-finiteness required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got $(\mu \otimes \lambda)(C)=\int_{\Omega} \int_0^{f(\omega)} d\lambda d\mu(\omega)$. Isn't this $\int_{\Omega} f(\omega) d\mu(\omega)$ or $\int f d\mu$?. To prove measurability of $C$ write $C^{c}$ as $\cup_{r\in \mathbb Q} \{(\omega ,t): f(\omega) <r)\}\cap \{(\omega ,t): r<t\}$.

Comment: Can you help me with the first part then?

Comment: @Coherent I already did that.

Comment: Please note that it hasn't been mentioned that $f$ is measurable! Or is it trivially assumed?

Comment: @Coherent If $f$ is not measurable then both parts are false. In fact you cannot even talk about $\int f d\mu$.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: I guess it should be $(\mu \otimes \lambda)(C)=\int_{\Omega} \int_0^{f(\omega)} d\lambda d\mu(\omega)$ rather than $(\mu \otimes \lambda)(C)=\int_{\Omega} \int_0^{f(\omega)} dt d\mu(\omega)$, then is it still done?

Comment: @Coherent Sorry, that was  a typo.